# How do i solve this error: FirebaseError: Expected type 'mc', but it was: a custom yc object?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I created a app on **Nextjs** (js) and **Firebase**. And I added **Stripe** extension to make a subscription system. I'm not very experienced with this new version 9 of firebase so it was hard to do this because I followed a tutorial that using version 8 and ts. I still managed to make most of the things work except this that is giving me this error.

This is the tutorial: https://youtu.be/P0Udy2Gi7n8?t=859 (my problem at 14:19)

**I'm having the error here:**

```
import getStripe from "./initializeStripe";
import { db } from '../firebase/firebaseClient'
import { doc, getDoc, addDoc, setDoc, setCol, onSnapshot, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid) {

    const docData = {
        price: "price_1KvNgoI6qyGEmrlgKU3miVmT",
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    };
  
    const checkoutSessionRef = await setDoc(collection(db, "users", uid, "checkout_sessions"), docData); //ERROR


    onSnapshot(getDoc(doc(checkoutSessionRef)), (snap) => {
        const { sessionId } = snap.data();

        if (sessionId) {
            // We have a session, let's redirect to checkout
            // Init Stripe
            const stripe = getStripe();
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId })
        }
    });
```

The error is the following:

**Unhandled Runtime Error**
FirebaseError: Expected type 'mc', but it was: a custom yc object

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkGA6.png)

[Firebase config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG5wz.png)

Comment: Error is hapenning on: setDoc. Also the function createCheckoutSession is being called when i press the button to make the stripe payment. All the help is highly appreciated 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setDoc()` takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as first parameter but you are passing a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference). Try using `addDoc()` instead:

```
await addDoc(collection(db, "users", uid, "checkout_sessions"), {...data})
```

This will add a document with a randomly generated document ID. If you want to use specify the document yourself, then you can use `setDoc()` as shown below:

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid, "checkout_sessions", "DOC_ID"), {...data})
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried and im getting a different error now: Unhandled Runtime Error
FirebaseError: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/6LEKMjgw7FXJXKC0zqxkA4TSopk2/checkout_sessions/jeLmttN8Z7bNxEW1hS4W/ErPSlFueJDeywYFTIVqR has 5.

Comment: Update: I checked and is creating the document even with the error. https://pasteboard.co/5XXjluSagDQ7.png

Comment: @BrunoFerreira you have a `/` in document ID. That's not allowed in a document ID. Where is that ID coming from? You can use addDoc() instead and store that value as a field in doucment instead.

Comment: The uid is comming from here: https://pasteboard.co/pCAxIA0EK0g3.png But i don't understand what you mean by having a / in a document ID. Sorry

Comment: Update: Your answer solve the issue. I'm just having some trouble with Stripe now. Aside from that is working. Thanks you very much for the help. Have a great day.